# switching between views in iphone programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View Controllers: How to switch between views programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910994/view-controllers-how-to-switch-between-views-programmatically)

i want to go to another view from one view on a button click 
please help me........
thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323942/iphone-how-to-switch-between-subviews-that-were-created-in-interface-builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `UINavigationController` to display the first view. When the user taps your button, call the navigation controller's `pushViewController:animated:` method. To return to the previous view programmatically, call one of the `pop...ViewController...` methods (though this may not be required, since the navigation controller itself can handle "back" button taps).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the `uiNevigationController` then use:

```
[self.view addSubView:objectOfSecondPage.view];
```

and add this on the back button in the next page

```
[removeFrom SuperView];
```