# Switching nib files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a View Controller inside my MainWindow.xib file that loads the nib "Cover" when loaded.  Cover (and the rest of my pages) is simply a nib file containing it's Owner, First Responder and a View.  There is also an associated class declaration.

In MainViewController.m I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

 [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cover" owner:self options:nil];
 [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

This successfully loads the Cover of my app.  On a button press I'd like to have a function switch Cover with Page1.  I tried:

```
-(IBAction)funcGoToPage:(id)sender{

 [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Page1" owner:self options:nil];

}
```

This function is also in MainViewController.  I know the function is being called but It doesn't seem to do anything.  Is the new nib showing up underneath the current nib?  Do I have to release the current nib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you want users to navigate, you either need to add the view of the nib as a subview to your current view, or push a new viewController on to the stack using a navigationController.  [Here](http://theappleblog.com/2009/04/15/iphone-dev-sessions-create-a-navigation-based-application/) is a tutorial on using a navigationController.  Or, if you just want to exchange them, [here is a link to a SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910994/view-controllers-how-to-switch-between-views-programmatically/911252#911252) for just that.