# Switching to a new ViewController in a different ViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm aware that you can switch from one ViewController to another using an intermediary Class, as seen in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910994/view-controllers-how-to-switch-between-views-programmatically).

What I want to know is, is there any way to switch to a different view controller directly from another view controller?  Like, load the view in the current view controller, and release the one you're in immediately after?

Thanks.

Comment: What would the purpose of doing that be? What is your end goal?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is how to retain 1 view controller.

What you can do is when you add your new View Controller, add it to your parent view controller and remove the current view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Using UINavigationController is one way: `[navigationController pushViewController:animated:]`. The other "official" way is to display the next view as a modal view: `[someVC presentModalViewController:]`, but this is deprecated since iOS 6.

The iOS 6 way is: - `(void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var currentVC:UIViewController!
> let firstVC = yourViewcontroller1()
> let secondVC = yourViewcontroller2()
> ```

```
func setupChildViewControllers(){
    self.addChildViewController(firstVC)
    self.addChildViewController(secondVC)
    self.view.addSubview(firstVC.view)
    self.currentVC = firstVC
}

func replaceController(oldVC:UIViewController,newVC:UIViewController){
    self.addChildViewController(newVC)

    self.transitionFromViewController(oldVC, toViewController: newVC, duration: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: nil) { (finished) -> Void in
        if finished {
            newVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
            oldVC.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
            oldVC.removeFromParentViewController()
            self.currentVC = newVC
        }else{
            self.currentVC = oldVC
        }
    }
}
```