# How to CLOSE View Controller

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller

Please help me.
I have "View Controller(VC) 1" + button "End" and VC 2
I want to end "VC 1" and Switch to VC2 when I touch a button "End".
I tried searching online but only "Switch view"... but SWITCHING isn't ENDING

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by end a view controller?

If you want to pop it off a navigation controller, you can use

```
[self.navigationController popViewController];
```

If you want to forcefully close your app (this will get it rejected) use

```
exit(0);
```

---

**EDIT:**

Now you have somewhat improved your question, I can tell you that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/910994/840973) question provides a good overview on switching views.

The top answer uses code from a book called "[Beginning iPhone Development](http://iphonedevbook.com)" which I would highly recommend if you are just starting out with iPhone Programming.

Comment: Thank for your answer./
I want to END VC 1 and go to VC 2... but not close my app/
and not use popover/