# addSubView not working, attempting to switch views

Tags: objective-c, addsubview

//  ViewController.m

```
1: - (IBAction)doNE:(id)sender {
2:
3:     [self.view removeFromSuperview];
4:     [self.view addSubView:MasterViewController];
4: }
```

Error on line 4: "Unexpected interface name `MasterViewController` :expected expression".
I have two view controllers: `ViewController` and `MasterViewController`. I've set it up so that the first view is a `ViewController` but I'm trying to get a button to change the view.

Comment: first clear what you want to do ? want to dismiss (remove) the view Controller. ?

Comment: There are two screens, I want to switch from the start screen to the second screen. The project is a phone book, the first screen is the contact edit/create screen, the second screen is a tableview with the list of contacts.

Comment: So you want to move first ViewController to MasterViewController.

Comment: I'm knew to this, so I'm not entirely sure of the technicality, but I'm just trying to change screen after I press a button

Comment: if you want to move from One View Controller to another try this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910994/view-controllers-how-to-switch-between-views-programmatically

Comment: It look like you are missing basic. so is you want to learn got to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Move First OneViewController to AnotherViewController using this.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    MasterViewController *createUserController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] keyWrapper:keyChainWrapper];
    [self presentViewController:createUserController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And if you Using UINavigationViewController you can push the ViewController like

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:createUserController  animated:YES];
```

and back using

```
[self.navigationController popViewController:createUserController animated:YES];
```

Comment: use of undeclared identifier "keyChainWrapper"

Comment: I removed the keychainwrapper which was causing some error, it compiled, but then when I pressed the button, it threw an exception

Comment: sorry I had to get off the computer, not sure if you will see these messages anymore, the error is: use of undeclared identifier "keyChainWrapper"

Answer (score 1):

```
MasterViewController *obj = [MasterViewController alloc]init];
self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

you can use this code snippet .This will push a new view controller. and will give u a back button functionality to go to previous view controller.

Comment: Hi, thanks, that compiled, but when I clicked the button, nothing happened

Comment: Sorry, I've used the log thing before but I'm too noob to be able to get that thing to come up again haha

Comment: wht r u talking?if u don't tell me the log statement how will i help u ?

Comment: NSLog(@"",obj); what do I put inside the quotation marks to get it working